# Nokia x100 error no devices/emulators found

Tags: recovery-mode

My Nokia x100 turns on but never goes passed the Nokia logo, USB debugging wasn't turned on when this happened so I'm stuck on how to either put into recovery mode or try to flash phone, have kali Linux. I plug in phone but my computer can't find it

Comment: May be using one of the common key combinations like holding Vol-Down+Power?